# Why was a question closed? Was my triage review wrong?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, triage

I recently reviewed a question in triage:

*https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/27513641*

The question was closed after review with "Needs details/Clarity". I reviewed the question as "Looks OK".

The question, as written, appears clear to me. They are asking how to play a video backwards at user definable speed, using libvlc.

I'm wondering if I should have reviewed this as "Flag" and how I would avoid misclassifying a similar question?

Comment: The question states that they're able to do fast-forward but not "fast backward" which makes it sound like they're trying to make it rewind, but then just say "play backwards". Then in the code comments they say they want it to go backwards "with more playback rate". That part is a bit confusing. I'm also not sure why you think they want it at a user definable speed, unless that's something that's obvious from elsewhere int the code itself.

Comment: "Looks ok" to me too (I disagree with @BSMP assessment that "rewind" and "play backward" are significantly different...) Would wait for Samuel Liew to comment... Somewhat hard to know reasoning as there are no comment nor votes by either C++ or vlc-qt official experts. Possibly closure is unrelated to post but rather user (also unlikely as I'd expect deletion in such case).

Comment: A little borderline case, I initially thought it was just a code dump. Now reopened.

Comment: It's unfortunately all too common that you understand a question and someone else doesn't. Whether a question needs more details or clarity depends greatly on how well you understand the subject and/or the mindset of the person asking the question.